# CocoaLumberjack and NSLog in other libraries

Tags: ios, logging, nslog, cocoalumberjack

I'm using [CocoaLumberjack](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaLumberjack) for all the logging in my app. Using this I can log straight to a file by using DDLogVerbose(...) or any of the available variants.

I'm also using [fmdb](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) (SQLite wrapper). The problem is that this library uses NSLog() and none if its output ends up on my log file.

Is there a way to capture NSLog's output and redirect it to CocoaLumberjack's? Or if that's not possible, just "rewrite" NSLog() so that it actually executes DDLogVerbose()?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding

```
#define NSLog DDLogInfo
```

to the top of the other libraries. Of course you will need to

```
#include "Logging.h"
```

for it to work.

Comment: Thank you! This works great for my own NSLog statements, but not for Apple's log statements.

Answer (score 1):

This may work, but it could also create an infinite loop since CocoaLumberjack is using NSLog, so a redefinition with DDLogInfo could mess things up. You just need to try and see.

Comment: You are correct, there is an infinite loop. Is there any workaround for this?